# Android.Net in MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, networking, vpn, maui

In my VPN client for Android, I use Xamarin to establish a VPN connection with the server. Recently, it was decided to switch to MAUI. How can I establish a VPN connection using MAUI? Is there something similar in MAUI to Android.Net ?

I tried to solve the problem using Connectivity , but I didn 't find the right solution

Comment: The same API calls you used before should still work.  Since you haven’t posted any actual code it’s impossible to give specific advice

Comment: Put Android-specific code in your Maui project's `Android` folder. There, you can do `Xamarin.Android` API calls, just like your previous project.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, Thank you very much, you helped me out a lot. These were the first attempts to understand MAUI, I did not immediately understand the architecture of the project.

Comment: place android specific code in platfrom/android folder but remove android in namespace of your class file because then I could not able to use Android library

Answer (score 0):

If you create your ".CS" files in the "/Platforms/Android" folder you have access to Android, Android.Net, and Android.APP or any other namespace that you used in your Xamarin project. then you can use `Android.Net.VpnService` class.